# Точка в условии if

Tags: javascript

Что означает точка в условии `if`?

Пример:

```
id = 70;
var site = window;
if (site.id) {
    document.write('ok');
}
```

Comment: А точка в следующей строке тебя не смущает? Учи js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращения к свойству объекта. http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro - почитайте это